# Built in .NET key/value pair configSection handler for app.config

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, app-config

I remember reading once that .NET had a built in configSection handler that could handle a collection of key/value pairs without having to code my own custom classes.  Similar to `appSettings`, but I can name the containing tag my own name and just start listing key/value pairs.

Anyone know if this exists and what it is called?

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="myKeys" type="Some.Built.In.Assembly, Some.Built.In.Assembly" />
  </configSections>

  <myKeys>
    <add key="1" value="1" />
    <add key="2" value="2" />
    <add key="3" value="3" />
  </myKeys>
```

Comment: I believe it is System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler. Example: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053102-1.aspx

Comment: Sam, why don't you put your comment as an answer? That is what I was looking for.

Comment: It was an answer. Some people on here like following instructions to the extreme. Since you asked your question in a way that suggested you had seen it before, I answered it in a way that suggested it might be the answer. Somebody decided because of the way I answered your question, it was a comment, not an answer. It's one of the things I dislike most about Wiki type systems. I will repost it more definitively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler. An example of its usage can be found here: [4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053102-1.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215954/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053102-1.aspx)

(Edited the typo in the class name)

Comment: This link now goes to a clickbait site.   Answer is correct though.  :)